# PHP PDO не удается обновить таблицу в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь заставить вот этот код обходить таблицы и поправлять в нем ссылки. С поиском и заменой скрипт справляется отлично, но почему-то обновлять записи в таблице не хочет - обновляется только 1 запись и все:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "Welcome";
$mysql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=UTF-8','user','12345');
if (!$mysql) die('Can\'t connect');

$tables = array(
    'categories',
    'news',
    'pages'
);

function getContent($table) {
    global $mysql;
    $fieldnum = 0;
    $fields = array();  
    $vals = array();
    $st = $mysql->query("SHOW FIELDS FROM `{$table}`"); 
    while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $fields[$fieldnum]=$row["Field"];       
        $fieldnum++;
    }
    $totalfields=$fieldnum;
    $res = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `{$table}`");
    $sql = "UPDATE `:table` SET :field = ':val' WHERE `:idf` = :id;";       
    while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$res->columnCount();$j++) {                   
            $rs = str_replace('index.php/','',$row[$j],$m);
            if ($rs && $m>0) {
                if ($table == 'categories')
                $prim= 'cat_id';
                elseif($table == 'news') $prim= 'news_id';
                elseif($table == 'pages') $prim= 'page_id';
                else $prim= $table.'_id';

                            $upd = $mysql->prepare($sql);
                $update = $upd->execute(array(
                ':table'=>$table,
                ':field'=>$fields[$j],
                ':val'=>$rs,
                ':idf'=>$prim,
                ':id'=>$row[0]
                ));             
            }
        }
    }   
}

foreach ($tables as $t) {
    getContent($t);
}
```

Просьба помочь. Никак не разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$update = $upd->execute(array(
                ':table'=>$table,
                ':field'=>$fields[$j],
                ':val'=>$rs,
                ':idf'=>$prim,
                ':id'=>$row[0]
                ));
```

Должно быть так:

```
$update = $upd->execute(array(
                'table'=>$table,
                'field'=>$fields[$j],
                'val'=>$rs,
                'idf'=>$prim,
                'id'=>$row[0]
                ));
```

То есть в массиве данных : в ключах не используется.

Comment: Как выяснилось, если в фрагменте
$sql = "UPDATE `:table` SET :field = ':val' WHERE `:idf` = :id;";
убрать кавычки вот так:
$sql = "UPDATE :table SET :field = :val WHERE :idf = :id;";
То все заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте просто вытащить

```
$upd = $mysql->prepare($sql);
```

за пределы цикла **for** (пишите сразу после **$sql**).

Я не вижу тут практического смысла выполнять "подготовку" в самом цикле. В самом цикле надо менять только сами параметры.